# How to create a form with a header and detail section

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

Does anyone know of any resources I could access that would show how i'd make a custom form, that allows for a single header section of data, but with a repeating detail section? Such as in an order header with multiple order lines (for example).

I'd like to use the Custom Forms module, and have it so that the end users can create their own header\detail forms without the need for any programmer.  The resulting forms would then be exported onto into an integration layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be a bit more specific? 
Are you trying to use the custom forms module for that? or is it your own? 
Orchard can use your own Views and Controllers, if you want to. 
If it is public-faced you only have to decorate it with [Themed] and instead passing the entire view, can return just a shape.

Comment: Update the description, ta.

Comment: You can extend the Custom Forms Module adding Fields, so you might be able to create something to handle that 'repeating' behavior. There are module in the Gallery that handle Forms [link](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.oforms).  If you do not like your end-users to have so much access to the underlying funct, i do strongly recommend for you to build your own module.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify more, I'm thinking more of the site administrator would setup the forms, not the actual end users.

Comment: Then, check out that link. or build your own Field to handle that 'repeating' behavior.  Elaborating the specific behavior, wouldn't harm either, as for this integration layer too.